# Quarkus Microprofile Rest Client, how to handle errors differently

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

I have 2 Quarkus services, one acts as an Edge-service and the other one as a Downstream service, the communication is done through Quarkus MicroProfile Rest-API client. Now Downstream service may return some kind of Bad request error (4xx) state with Json body. my problem now is Edge service is throwing 500 error with WebApplicationException because of that, is there a way to populate same response code and body from Downstream Service to Edge Service ?

Comment: You mean ignore the fact that the downstream services does not return a 2XX response and use the payload regardless?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

This exception is thrown by the default rest client `ResponseExceptionMapper`.

You should be able to disable it by adding the following property to `application.properties`:

```
microprofile.rest.client.disable.default.mapper=true
```

See the [Default ResponxeExceptionMapper](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0.html#_default_responseexceptionmapper) and [ResponseExceptionMapper](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0.html#_responseexceptionmapper) sections of the MicroProfile Rest Client specification.

Comment: I tried the above property in addition to "org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.disable.default.mapper=false" and It didn't work! does it have different naming when it is a Quarkus App ?

Comment: Yes it does. Which version of the rest client do you use? Could you open an issue in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues with a reproducer?

Comment: As a temp solution I used what you suggested "ResponseExceptionMapper", for the above configuration property I'll open a ticket for it once I've a reproducer ready, I am using Quarkus "1.13.2".

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the value of the property, I fixed the response now