# RestClient Error javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Unknown error, status code 404

Tags: rest, runtime-error, resteasy, quarkus, rest-client

I'm trying to request from a Quarkus's api to Jersey's api, but Jersey API returns a 404 error:

**javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Unknown error, status code 404**

**It looks like quarkus rest client doesn't recognize or can't parse the payload json.**

Did you already get something like that?

the payload should be something like that:

```
{
    "code": 404,
    "description": "some description....",
    "label": "API_ERROR_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "Requested Object not found"
}
```

The code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MachineService {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    ICoreSummaryRest iCoreSummaryRest;

    public Boolean transferDatacollector(ObjectNode transferDatacollector) {
        try {
            String resp = iCoreSummaryRest.updateDataCollectosTransfer
                (transferDatacollector.toString());
            return Boolean.valueOf(resp);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

interface

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.annotation.RegisterClientHeaders;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.annotation.RegisterProvider;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;


@Path("/")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="country-api")
@RegisterClientHeaders(CustomHeadersRest.class)
public interface ICoreSummaryRest {

@PUT
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("datacollectors/transfer/")
    public String updateDataCollectosTransfer(String transferDatacollectorJSON);

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- The Basics -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-project-resource</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependências Gerais Quarkus BOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--  <dependency>
              <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
              <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-graphql</artifactId>
          </dependency> -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client</groupId>
              <artifactId>microprofile-rest-client-api</artifactId>
          </dependency>
          <!-- Dependências do Projeto -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project-service</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependência JTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependência mycompany -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build Settings -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: **Hi !!!
I fixed it using  ResponseExceptionMapper to extract and parse the content to  String**

Comment: `public class DefaultMicroprofileRestClientExceptionMapper implements ResponseExceptionMapper {

    Response resp = null;
    String responseAsString = null; `

Comment: `public Throwable toThrowable(Response response) {

        try {
            response.getEntity();

            ByteArrayInputStream in = (ByteArrayInputStream) response.getEntity();
            int n = in.available();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
            in.read(bytes, 0, n);
            responseAsString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Or any encoding.

        } catch (Exception var3) {
            System.out.println(var3);
        }

        return new RestClientException(responseAsString, response);
    }`

Comment: `public boolean handles(int status, MultivaluedMap headers) {
        return status >= 400;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return 5000;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the body you can catch the error like this:

```
try {
  String resourceResponse = errorRestClient.getResource();
} catch (WebApplicationException e) {
  String respStr = e.getResponse().readEntity(String.class);
  LOGGER.error(respStr);
}
```

Which will print this for the following mockbin at http://mockbin.org/bin/3144eda0-9fa7-4893-90ee-5d624d51bcd2

> 2022-01-30 17:59:45,851 ERROR [org.acm.arc.ErrorHTTPrestAPI]
> (vert.x-eventloop-thread-11) {     "description": "some
> description....",
> "label": "API_ERROR_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND",
> "message": "Requested Object not found" }

My interface looks like this

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/")
@RegisterRestClient(baseUri="http://mockbin.org/bin/3144eda0-9fa7-4893-90ee-5d624d51bcd2")
public interface ErrorRestClient {

    @GET
    @Path("")
    String getResource();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278358/quarkus-microprofile-rest-client-how-to-handle-errors-differently),
when RestClient receives one response different from 2xx it automatically throws this exception.

Perhaps you can disable the ResponseExceptionMapper or create one interceptor to handle this exception.

Below I just quote the answer from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278358/quarkus-microprofile-rest-client-how-to-handle-errors-differently)

> This exception is thrown by the default rest client ResponseExceptionMapper.

> You should be able to disable it by adding the following property to application.properties:

```
microprofile.rest.client.disable.default.mapper=false
```

> See the Default ResponxeExceptionMapper and ResponseExceptionMapper sections of the MicroProfile Rest Client specification.